# Bicep: unable to set storage account to web app resource

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I've some experience using Azure CLI, Az Module and ARM templates... Anyway I'm experimenting problems in setting a storage account to a web app.

This is the **bicep** source (still a work in progress):

```
@allowed([
  'dev'
  'qta'
  'ppd'
  'prd'
])
param targetEnv string = 'dev'
@allowed([
  'southafricanorth'
  'southafricawest'
  'northeurope'
  'westeurope'
  'australiaeast'
  'australiasoutheast'
  'australiacentral'
  'australiacentral2'
  'eastasia'
  'southeastasia'
  'brazilsouth'
  'brazilsoutheast'
  'centralus'
  'eastus'
  'eastus2'
  'westus'
  'westus2'
  'westus3'
  'northcentralus'
  'southcentralus'
])
param location string = 'westeurope'
param planName string = 'testplan1'
param planGroup string = 'rgdoftempdev'

var locationMap = {
  'southafricanorth':   'af'
  'southafricawest':    'af'
  'northeurope':        'eu'
  'westeurope':         'eu'
  'australiaeast':      'pc'
  'australiasoutheast': 'pc'
  'australiacentral':   'pc'
  'australiacentral2':  'pc'
  'eastasia':           'as'
  'southeastasia':      'as'
  'brazilsouth':        'sa'
  'brazilsoutheast':    'sa'
  'centralus':          'us'
  'eastus':             'us'
  'eastus2':            'us'
  'westus':             'us'
  'westus2':            'us'
  'westus3':            'us'
  'northcentralus':     'us'
  'southcentralus':     'us'
}
var locationAcr = locationMap[location]

// var hash = substring(uniqueString(subscription().subscriptionId), 0, 4)
var appName = 'bvdof'
var insightsName = '${appName}-appinsights-${locationAcr}-${targetEnv}'
var storageName =  '${appName}sa${locationAcr}${targetEnv}'
var webAppName = '${appName}-webapp-${locationAcr}-${targetEnv}'

resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2021-06-01' = {
  name: storageName
  location: location
  kind: 'StorageV2'
  sku: {
    name: 'Premium_LRS'
  }
  properties: {
    minimumTlsVersion: 'TLS1_2'
    allowBlobPublicAccess: true
    networkAcls: {
      bypass: 'AzureServices'
      defaultAction: 'Allow'
    }
    supportsHttpsTrafficOnly: true
    encryption: {
      keySource: 'Microsoft.Storage'
      services: {
        blob: {
          keyType: 'Account'
          enabled: true
        }
        file: {
          keyType: 'Account'
          enabled: true
        }
      }
    }
    accessTier: 'Hot'
  }
}

resource appInsights 'Microsoft.Insights/components@2020-02-02' = {
  name: insightsName
  location: location
  kind: 'web'
  properties: {
    Application_Type: 'web'
    publicNetworkAccessForIngestion: 'Enabled'
    publicNetworkAccessForQuery: 'Enabled'
  }
}

resource webApplication 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2021-02-01' = {
  dependsOn: [
    appInsights
    storageAccount
  ]
  name: webAppName
  location: resourceGroup().location
  kind: 'app'
  properties: {
    httpsOnly: true
    serverFarmId: '/subscriptions/${subscription().id}/resourceGroups/${planGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/${planName}'
    clientAffinityEnabled: true
    siteConfig: {
      appSettings: [
        {
          name: 'APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY'
          value: appInsights.properties.InstrumentationKey
        }
        // {
        //   name: 'AzureWebJobsDashboard'
        //   value: 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${storageAccount.name};EndpointSuffix=${environment().suffixes.storage};AccountKey=${listKeys(storageAccount.id, storageAccount.apiVersion).keys[0].value}'
        // }
        // {
        //   name: 'AzureWebJobsStorage'
        //   value: 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${storageAccount.name};EndpointSuffix=${environment().suffixes.storage};AccountKey=${listKeys(storageAccount.id, storageAccount.apiVersion).keys[0].value}'
        // }
        {
          name: 'WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING'
          value: 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${storageName};AccountKey=${listKeys(storageAccount.id, storageAccount.apiVersion).keys[0].value}'
        }
        {
          name: 'WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE'
          value: webAppName
        }
        {
          name: 'ANCM_ADDITIONAL_ERROR_PAGE_LINK'
          value: 'https://${webAppName}.scm.azurewebsites.net/detectors?type=tools&name=eventviewer'
        }
        {
          name: 'APPINSIGHTS_PROFILERFEATURE_VERSION'
          value: '1.0.0'
        }
        {
          name: 'APPINSIGHTS_SNAPSHOTFEATURE_VERSION'
          value: '1.0.0'
        }
        {
          name: 'APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING'
          value: 'InstrumentationKey=${appInsights.properties.InstrumentationKey};IngestionEndpoint=https://${location}.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This is the error I get after partially failed deployment (storage and app insights created):

```
{"status":"Failed","error":{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"BadRequest","message":"{\r\n  \"Code\": \"BadRequest\",\r\n  \"Message\": \"There was a conflict. The remote name could not be resolved: 'bvdofsaeudev.file.core.windows.net'\",\r\n  \"Target\": null,\r\n  \"Details\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"Message\": \"There was a conflict. The remote name could not be resolved: 'bvdofsaeudev.file.core.windows.net'\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"Code\": \"BadRequest\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"ErrorEntity\": {\r\n        \"ExtendedCode\": \"01020\",\r\n   
     \"MessageTemplate\": \"There was a conflict. {0}\",\r\n        \"Parameters\": [\r\n          \"The remote name could not be resolved: 'bvdofsaeudev.file.core.windows.net'\"\r\n        ],\r\n        \"Code\": \"BadRequest\",\r\n        \"Message\": \"There was a conflict. The remote name could not be resolved: 'bvdofsaeudev.file.core.windows.net'\"\r\n      }\r\n    }\r\n  ],\r\n  \"Innererror\": null\r\n}"}]}}
```

What is wrong with this definition?

Comment: as per the error the storage account you are creating doesn't have file service  , it has only blob service . thats why its not able to get the file.core.net remote name.

Comment: let me check and get back here

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT weird thing is that I create exactly this kind of storage account using an ARM template and configure it with success via Az Module. Anyway thanks for your comment.

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT found too, thanks to your help... I changed sku Standard_LRS. I checked my previouis template and the piece of code that use it set this value. With Premium_LRS we've just the blob component. Omg I've done so much questions about it :) lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code and faced the same error as you can see below:

[image]

The error in the code is that you are using a `Premium_LRS` sku and kind is `storageV2` . So , it doesn't create a File service in the Storage account only Blob service . For which reason , app is not able to find the remote name of the storage account file server.

**There can be two solutions as below:**

1. Just Changing the Sku name from `Premium_LRS` to `Standard_LRS` in the storage account resource as below:

```
resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2021-06-01' = {
  name: storageName
  location: location
  kind: 'StorageV2'
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard_LRS'
  }
  properties: {
    minimumTlsVersion: 'TLS1_2'
    allowBlobPublicAccess: true
    networkAcls: {
      bypass: 'AzureServices'
      defaultAction: 'Allow'
    }
    supportsHttpsTrafficOnly: true
    encryption: {
      keySource: 'Microsoft.Storage'
      services: {
        blob: {
          keyType: 'Account'
          enabled: true
        }
        file: {
          keyType: 'Account'
          enabled: true
        }
      }
    }
    accessTier: 'Hot'
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

2. If you want to use `Premium_LRS` then Change the Kind to `FileStorage` instead of `StorageV2` as below, so that it create a premium storage account with File service and not Blob service:

```
resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2021-06-01' = {
  name: storageName
  location: location
  kind: 'FileStorage'
  sku: {
    name: 'Premium_LRS'
  }
  properties: {
    minimumTlsVersion: 'TLS1_2'
    allowBlobPublicAccess: true
    networkAcls: {
      bypass: 'AzureServices'
      defaultAction: 'Allow'
    }
    supportsHttpsTrafficOnly: true
    encryption: {
      keySource: 'Microsoft.Storage'
      services: {
        blob: {
          keyType: 'Account'
          enabled: true
        }
        file: {
          keyType: 'Account'
          enabled: true
        }
      }
    }
    accessTier: 'Hot'
  }
}
```

**Outputs:**

[image]

[image]